# flutter app splash screen freeze any way to resolve

Tags: flutter, google-play-console

I have created a flutter app and created its apk in release mode. The app is working on my all devices Samsung note, vivo moto. Then I uploaded android app bundle to play store but when i downloaded the app from play then app gets freeze at splash screen in samsung note.

Comment: Have you used the firebase_crashlytics package in your app??

if not then use and check the error from firebase.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some exception in your app. Make sure you haven't receive any exception in Debug console. if you haven't receive any exception in your console then run your app in release mode using this command.

```
flutter run --release
```

You will get your exception in your console.

Comment: i have tested its working fine . I have tested it on firebase test lab with the same model number its working fine. Then what can i do any help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get the solution . Clear the app data and then it will work . Now I will try to catch that exception